# How can i connect a modelfield with a particular information belonging to him?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am making a web app that will handle cricket matches what I need to do is to assign an specific information belonging to a model field For e.g it's player1 so I have to make it able for the user to assign the information belonging to that particular field like what's his batting turn etc.
How should I make the models for this situation

Comment: Your question is totally unclear, and also your comment. It may be a language issue, but what does "connect player to a field" mean. Maybe have a look at [relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) in django. You have to think in terms of objects (object oriented programming). A "player" is an object. A "match" or "game" is also an object. Maybe a "turn" is also an object (which describes which player is batting, which direction they're batting, what time it is, what the outcome is of the turn, etc...). Each object has its own model.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation you can create Models like this:

```
class Player(models.Model):
   player_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   player_turn = model.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The player_turn will be a boolean field, having value True if it's the player's turn, False otherwise. Fetch the player by his unique identifier and update player_turn field accordingly.

Comment: You haven't understood the question probably. I want to a field to have an information related to it like when the user will bat or ball and for that i also need to create a model field what i want is a solution so these players can connect to that field but each information should be connect to that unique player

Comment: based on your comments will the boolean field not help.

Comment: Probably it will not help